# protractor variables reuse efficiency

Tags: javascript, protractor

I read somewhere (I can no longer find the article) that when calling an element multiple times it is better (**It takes less time and uses less resources**) to use a variable like this:

```
var proceed = element(by.className('proceed');
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(proceed).click()), timeout, 'no proceed found!');
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(proceed).click()), timeout, 'no proceed found!');
```

as opposed to calling the element like this:

```
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.className('proceed')).click()), timeout, 'no proceed found!');
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.className('proceed')).click()), timeout, 'no proceed found!');
```

because when calling a variable, it only has to search the DOM for the element once, after which it will save it for later use. If this is true,how does this work and how do I "force" protractor to search for the element?

Comment: you have written code to search the same element multiple times - so it will be searched multiple times. Programming languages are explicit - they do exactly what you asked.

Comment: so you are saying that whenever I call the element through `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.className('proceed')).click()), timeout, 'no proceed found!');` I am searching for it again. what about in the first case?

Comment: "element(by.className('proceed');" does not immediately search for element. it stores some selector-builder to be later used for searching element in dom in asynchronous mode. it is actually called twice in the first and the second code snippets.

Comment: @Segg3r so there is no practical difference?

Answer (score 0):

In protractor, there is no efficiency gain. Protractor does not implement any caching strategy. Every time you call some action on an element, like the `click()` method, it will go out and find the element each and every time. It looks better, though, and makes your test more maintainable, when you declare the variable instead of repeating it each time.

In case you are curious, a cached version in protractor would look like this:

```
element(by.className('proceed')).getWebElement().then(function(proceed) {
    proceed.click().then(function() {
        console.log('clicked proceed the first time');
    }, function() {
        console.log('unable to find proceed the first time (this should not happen)');
    });
    proceed.click().then(function() {
        console.log('clicked proceed the second time (this should not happen)');
    }, function() {
        console.log('unable to find proceed the second time (stale element)');
    });
});
```